# How to print a paragraph into one single long line in python

Tags: python, string, formatting

Paragraph="This is a long paragraph.Its printed on a single straight line.You can zoom your screen"

print(paragraph)

When I run the program,the paragraph is printed more than one line.I want the string to be printed on just one line even if all texts won't fit on the screen.

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with your terminal

Comment: Disable line wrap in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Many (/most) terminals have linewrap enabled by default. This means if a string is longer than the width of the terminal, it will wrap over to the next line.

Presuming you're using a gnome terminal, you can turn off linewrapping with

```
 tput rmam
```

and turn it back on with

```
tput smam
```

However you should note that this won't let you scroll horizontally to see the part of the paragraph that's been cut off. If you're developing an application and need it print without wrapping every time or on different systems, that might be a problem. Is there any specific reason you need this behaviour?

Comment: I made a live progress bar hard coded from scratch to show progress of Threadpoolexecutor.If all the strings printed on the progress bar fits the screen without line wrapping,the progress bar is working well by flushing output to stdout.But on devices with smaller screens,the strings line wrap and then makes the progress bar to keep on printing infinity after every refresh.I have uses shutil and now it's working after following instructions@JonSG

Comment: Fantastic - for future reference there's a good module for progress bars if you ever need a quick one: tqdm (https://tqdm.github.io/) although it's more limited than a custom one of course

Comment: tqdm module is limited,I prefer a custom progress bar

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually truncate your text and print only what will fit without wrapping rather than relying on your terminal to do that for you then you can use the `shutil` package to get the width (columns).

```py
import shutil

paragraph="""
This is a long paragraph.
Its printed on a single straight line.
You can zoom your screen.
This is a long paragraph.
Its printed on a single straight line.
You can zoom your screen.
This is a long paragraph.
Its printed on a single straight line.
You can zoom your screen.
This is a long paragraph.
Its printed on a single straight line.
You can zoom your screen.
""".replace("\n", " ").strip()

print("---------------")
print(paragraph)
print("---------------")
print()

columns, rows = shutil.get_terminal_size()
paragraph = paragraph[:columns]

print("---------------")
print(paragraph)
print("---------------")
```

That should result in something like the below. It looks right on my browser but I can't promise it does on yours.

```
---------------
This is a long paragraph. Its printed on a single straight line. You can zoom your
 screen. This is a long paragraph. Its printed on a single straight line. You can 
zoom your screen. This is a long paragraph. Its printed on a single straight line.
 You can zoom your screen. This is a long paragraph. Its printed on a single strai
ght line. You can zoom your screen.
---------------

---------------
This is a long paragraph. Its printed on a single straight line. You can zoom your
---------------
```

if you wanted to get fancy you could also add in ellipsis.

```py
if len(paragraph) > columns:
    paragraph = paragraph[:columns-3] + "..."
```

Hopefully giving you:

```
---------------
This is a long paragraph. Its printed on a single straight line. You can zoom y...
---------------
```

Comment: Thank you.Its working as I wanted .I wanted to use that consept in making my hard coded progress bar.All it's working well now.Thank you once more